# Unable to upgrade SQL DB from one edition (Basic) to other (Standard) with DR enabled

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have primary and secondary SQL DB with DR enabled in Basic edition.

When upgrading the primary DB edition, there was an exception 'The source database (primary) cannot have higher edition than the target database (Secondary). Upgrade the edition on the target before upgrading source.'

Tried to update the secondary database first and then provision the database in primary resulted in the exception 'The operation cannot be performed since the database 'dbname' is in a replication relationship'

Tried to delete the replication link and upgrade the secondary DB resulted in the exception 'The operation cannot be performed because the geo-replication link is part of a Failover Group. You must remove the database from the group in order to individually terminate or failover.'

In Azure portal, we are manually able to upgrade the Secondary DB. Would like to know how is it working in the backend. As we are trying to automate this process and az sql update is not working on the secondary DB with the above exceptions.

Please suggest possible solutions for automation of the upgrade from one edition to other with geo-replication enabled on DB.

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for that eg. customer was trying to rename database at the same time, so we failed the whole operation. We are not preventing updates based on whether db is in FG or not only sometimes on whether it is in geo replication or not (like renaming case mentioned above). Please provide the server name for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE APPLICATION ROLE weekly_receipts   
    WITH PASSWORD = '987G^bv876sPY)Y5m23'   
    , DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Sales;  
GO  

EXEC sys.sp_setapprole 'weekly_receipts', '987G^bv876sPY)Y5m23';  
GO  

SELECT USER_NAME();  
-- This will return the name of the application role, weekly_receipts
```

Answer (score 0):

We found the reason for the failure. Just removing the maxSizeBytes parameter from the update command worked.